# Magento var_dump all collections in use on a page

Tags: php, magento

Still learning magento coding.  I wonder is there a way I can print out all the values in the collections on any page I load on magento? This would be assuming I don't know the names of the collections being used.

This would be very helpful if it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a word of warning - if you are var_dump'ing collections, let alone every collection loaded for a given request, then you are most likely going to run in to problems - collections contain huge amounts of data.

What is it exactly that you require from each collection that you would need to do this?

Anyway, the only way to get this data that comes to mind would be to use an observer subscribed to:

```
core_collection_abstract_load_after
```

So as a head start...

Your config.xml would look similar to this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_YourModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </YourCompany_YourModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <core_collection_abstract_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>core_collection_abstract_load_after</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
            </core_collection_abstract_load_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model</class>
            </yourmodule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your observer would look like this...

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function core_collection_abstract_load_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        //Do what you want with each collection here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, you seem to be answering a lot of my questions recently.  I'll give this a go later today.

Comment: Hi Drew, so this will all me get all the values.  But what is the best way of 'seeing them'  if I try to `var_dump()` in the browser, often I will simply get a 'headers already sent error'.  Is there an alternative way?  I was thinking maybe writing the values I want to a file on the server, but this means I will have to constantly reload this file, is there a more convenient way?

Comment: I found a good solution `Mage::log();` To anyone else who needs to do this, you can read about it here http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/magento-initial-setup

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach and be it your new to Magento I would suggest using this:

- https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug

As it will offer other insight into the internal workings as well as collection and SQL info about the actual collection.

A view in action:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqvgrmebcu4

Comment: Hello my opinion on this would be the op would personally learn more from setting up own module and learning about events/observers etc than installing a 3rd party module. Seems to be a culture amongst some magento devs to just find an extension for everything